# Theme.MaterialComponents does not change font of dialog title

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

I am using the material components theming for our app. Now we want a custom font, which I managed to apply almost everywhere with the theme below, which uses the various `textAppearance...` attributes defined by material components.

This works very well, and the theme is also applied to the AlertDialogs almost everywhere -- message text and buttons have the custom font, buttons have the correct accent colors etc.

Only the dialog title keeps the Roboto font, no matter what.

[image: dialog with correct colors but wrong title font]

```
<!-- externalized font name for easier change -->
<string name="font_regular" translatable="false" tools:ignore="ReferenceType">@font/atma_regular</string>

<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle2</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.App.Body1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.App.Body2</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.App.Large</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.App.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmall">@style/TextAppearance.App.Small</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/font_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_regular</item>
</style>
...
```

I tried to define an extra theme for the alert dialogs like so:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.App.AlertDialog</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="Theme.App.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.DialogWindowTitle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/font_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

But that resets the colors and fonts everywhere. The only thing that is applied, is the textSize.

[image: custom dialog theme makes it worse]

It really shouldn't be so hard to achieve this, but I am out of ideas right now. I could apply the font programmatically, but that would be quite ugly.

Comment: You said custom font. What is inside of `@string/font_regular` ? just a string like `sans-serif`? Haven't you tried setting it directly? `<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>`

Comment: @Mohsen I added `@string/font_regular` to my question (on top). Value could also be sans-serif etc. As you can see in the screenshot, it works everywhere except for the title. I tried your suggestion but it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Ridcully how did you manage to change the title font in the end? Struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned the `AlertDialog` created by `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` uses the style defined by the **`textAppearanceSubtitle1`** attribute in your app theme.

Otherwise you can change the style used by the `AlertDialog` using something like:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
    R.style.MyTitle_ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message......")
    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .show();
```

In your style you have to customize the **`materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle`** attribute:

```
  <style name="MyTitle_ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">....</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">....</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">.....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your question I realized that I was using the incorrect attribute to assign the title style (`android:titleTextAppearance` instead of `android:windowTitleStyle`).

It looks like your issue has been fixed in the meantime, as your exact code seems to work for me as of today.

Comment: thanks to your comment, I finally found that android:windowTitleStyle is the one I need to style the goddamn dialog title!